# Floor division with small numbers returning wrong answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do some calculations in my python script but i'm getting some weird results. For example:

```
0.03 // 0.01
>>> 2.0
```

If I upscale the numbers I get the expected results:

```
3.0 // 1.0
>>> 3.0
```

I'm pretty sure that the answer for the first code snippet should be `3.0` and not `2.0`. Can someone explain me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Floating point rounding error doesn't stop happening just because you use `//`.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a duplicate `0.03/0.01 < 3.0` evaluates to `False`. The question seems to involve the semantics of `//` vs. `/` in a way that the proposed duplicate doesn't really explain.

Comment: On the other hand -- the second duplicate target (since added) *is* a genuine duplicate target.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the [floating point error](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). Note that with the above floor division, the remainder is not `0`:

```
0.03 % 0.01
# 0.009999999999999998
```

So if instead we divide by:

```
0.03 // 0.009
# 3.0
```

The answer is correct. Hence `0.03` is not entirely divisible by `0.01` without some remainder due to floating point limitations

Answer (score 3):

As yatu already mentioned, this is due to floating point errors.
Try this instead:

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal('0.03') // Decimal('0.01')
>>> 3
```